# Tune sound remixing

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My PC sound outputs to 5.1 sound system with subwoofer being able to play 45 Hz and more frequencies only. Some songs and movies was "looking" weird with portions being distorted or silent. I think I figured out what is the reason: when sound is intended to be within 20-45 Hz, it just doesn't come out. In this video, the whole second part of it is completely silent for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8gjsefNYpE - which exactly corresponds to my speakers specs.

Is there a way to remix 20-45 Hz to 46 Hz or something with alsa/pulseaudio? Or any other way to solve this problem? Besides spending 3k$ on new sound system ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your speaker can not play a certain frequency range you have to live with that or change the speaker. It can make sense to filter out those frequencies under certain circumstances.

However, your idea of "folding" the lower frequencies up into the reproducible range would result in unpleasant and distorted noise which likely was not intended by the producer of said pieces of sound.

You seem to forget the frequency corresponds to perceived pitch of a tone, it's not just a secondary quality of it.

Comment: Agree. If the frequency limitation is due to the speaker system there is no way to adjust audio in software to increase frequency range

Answer (score 1):

Pulseaudio has settings for lfe remixing

To safely customise Pulseaudio settings, copy default settings file to home folder

`cp /etc/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`

Only need to edit the new file to change settings and don't need sudo. Home folder settings are used instead of original settings, but if something doesn't work can delete new settings file and restart Pulseaudio with default settings

Open file ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
find this section:

```
; enable-remixing = yes
; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
; enable-lfe-remixing = no
; lfe-crossover-freq = 0
```

these settings are disabled by default
delete the semicolon ";" at beginning of each line to enable setting

Can't advise exact settings you would need, but there should be a combination of these 4 to suit your needs

Comment: I tried it before - didn't help :( - as I understand, it moves everything below specified frequencies to sub, which is actually already working well. I need something else: respecify 20-45 freqs as 46 or something. As I understand, I need to "tell" Pulseaudio/Soundcard that my sub can't play <46 freqs

Answer (score 0):

This could help too ... :

There are additional drivers in different music packages.

So you could install (--reinstall) packages rhythmbox and amarok.

> sudo apt-get install rhythmbox amarok

or if they are already installed, then:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox amarok

This helped in other similiar situations, where had been trouble with sound output.

Then do

> reboot